# What is standard web page load time?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

What is standard web page load time?

I know it depends on various factors like page size, internet speed, hardware/software configurations.

But is there any standard digit?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "standard" page load time, the main rule is "the faster is better" as [pages which load faster rank higher in search engines results](http://www.seochat.com/c/a/google-optimization-help/average-page-load-time-of-top-ranking-websites-in-google/).

Normally you should have [non-functional requirements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) which specify the acceptable response time for the web page.

If you don't have them - you can come up with your own criteria, however they can be different depending on the nature of your application. For example if your app is internal and generates huge reports - even several minutes can be considered acceptable, however if your app is i.e. online marketplace or retail shop during the Black Friday - every millisecond matters

According to [Akamai Report](https://www.scribd.com/document/300122029/Akamai-Performance-Matters-Key-Consumer-Insights-eBook#scribd)

- 49% of respondents expected web pages to load in under 2 seconds
- 30% expect a 1-second response
- 18% expected a site to load immediately

So I would strongly recommend to perform [all the necessary performance testing types](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough) and not only ensure that your application is "not worse than others", but to identify the [bottlenecks](https://qainsights.com/how-to-identify-bottlenecks-in-performance-testing/) and ensure that your application is fully utilizing the resources or [scales up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing) when the load gets higher hence provides smooth user experience no matter of the load.